# rm not working even the user is in the group

Tags: linux, files, permissions

I have a file owned by `ec2-user`.

```
ll
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user       6 Aug 25 10:52 testing_file2
```

I have added an user called `user1` into the `ec2-user` group.

```
usermod -aG ec2-user user1
```

Then I tried to remove the file from the user1, but its not working. But the user can do change the contents in the file.

```
rm testing_file2
rm: cannot remove ‘testing_file2’: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Do you have write permission on the _directory_?

Comment: yes, its `/tmp`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit

Comment: ec2-user will not be in the group until it logs in to its new setting. Try `su - user1` if you have not renewed the session.